# Тестовое задание

Tags: php, стек, интерпретатор

Попытался решить задачу с http://zoon.ru/job.php . (Не с целью устроится, а с целью саморазвития )

Уверен, что вышло с косяком. Возможно и не одним, т.к. первый раз творю подобное.
Уложился, как и указано в задании меньше чем за час.

Так как текст задания достаточно объемный, вы можете получить его тем же методом что и я

```
$quest_url = "http://zoon.ru/job.php?name=rijen&contact=false&cv=false";
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($quest_url));
print $response->description;
```

**Проблема в том, что где-то есть ошибка, т.к. первым элементом выхода второй из трех задач оказался null.**

Хоть он и обработался как *0*, т.к. висит проверка *is_numeric*, это не есть хорошо.

Получаю массив с задачами.

```
$tasks = $response->task;
```

Выставляю переменные по умолчанию

Стек и Выход - думаю понятно.

$IP это ключ массива команд задачи.

Старт нужен для того чтобы не выходить сразу в начале первой задачи из-за пустого стека.

```
$stack = array();
$out = array();
$task = 0;
$IP = 0;
$start = true;
```

### Сам код:

*Вставки таблицы для дебага =)*

```
print '<table>';
while(true){
if(!isset($tasks[$task][$IP]) or ($start!=true and empty($stack)) ){

    print "<tr><td colspan='3' ><b>Выход выполнения задачи $task : <b>" . json_encode(array_reverse($out)) . '</b></td></tr>';
    if(count($tasks)-1==$task){
        print "<tr><td colspan='3' ><b>Задач больше нет.</b></td></tr>";
        break;
    }else{
        print "<tr><td colspan='3' ><b>Переход к следующей задаче...</b></td></tr>";
        $task++;
        $IP = 0;
    }
    if(!empty($out)){
        foreach($out as $in_key){
            array_unshift($stack, $in_key);
        }
        $out=array();
    }

}else{
#   print '<tr>';
    $command = $tasks[$task][$IP];
#   print("<td>$command</td>");
    if(is_numeric($command)){
        $IP++;
        array_unshift($stack, $command);
    }else{
        switch($command){
            case 'DUP':
                $IP++;
                $p = array_shift($stack);
                array_unshift($stack, $p);
                array_unshift($stack, $p);
                break 1;
            case 'DEC':
                $IP++;
                $p = array_shift($stack);
                array_unshift($stack, $p-1);
                break 1;
            case 'IF':
                $IP++;
                $q = array_shift($stack);
                $p = array_shift($stack);
                if($p==0){
                    $IP = $IP+$q+3;
                }else{
                    $IP++;
                    array_shift($stack);
                }
                break 1;
            case 'DROP':
                $IP++;
                array_shift($stack);
                break 1;
            case 'G':
                $p = array_shift($stack);
                $IP+=$p-2;
                break 1;
            case 'MOVE':
                $IP++;
                $q = array_shift($stack);
                $p = array_shift($stack);
                $stack[$q]=$p;
                break 1;
            case 'CHR':
                $IP++;
                $p = array_shift($stack);
                array_unshift($stack, $p+2);
                break 1;
            case 'OUT':
                $IP++;
                $p = array_shift($stack);
                array_unshift($out,$p);
                break 1;
            case '*':
                $IP++;
                $q = array_shift($stack);
                $p = array_shift($stack);
                array_unshift($stack, $p*$q);
                break 1;
            case '+':
                $IP++;
                $q = array_shift($stack);
                $p = array_shift($stack);
                array_unshift($stack, $p+$q);
                break 1;
            default:
                print '</hr><B>Error, command not found!</b></hr>';
                break 2;
        }
    }
#   print '<td>' . count($stack) . '</td><td>' . count($out) .'</td>';
#   print '</tr>';
    if(isset($p)){unset($p);}
    if(isset($q)){unset($q);}
}
$start = false;
}
print '</table>';
```

Comment: в чем вопрос? )

Comment: У меня где-то просочился null.

Я уверен что сама задача составлена корректно.

Произойти это могло из-за некорректной обработки команды 'IF'.

Особенно, если читать само задание, там есть такой момент

"если $p==0, то $IP = $IP+$q+3; иначе $IP++ DROP"

Так же я мог неверно истолковать  команду "MOVE".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы зачем-то в кейсе `IF` еще раз снимаете элемент с вершины стека

```
    $IP++;
    array_shift($stack);
```

хотя по условию задачи этого вроде как не требуется.

К тому же кейс `MOVE` **заменит**, а не добавит, значение по индексу `$q` в том случае, если с таким же индексом уже что-то хранится в стеке. Остальное не смотрел.

Ну и для себя обратите внимание на такие вещи в php, как `is_null()` и `===`, по скольку `NULL` в php - это отдельный тип данных. Это я к тому, что можно попробовать отловить ситуацию, когда в переменной данные неподходящего типа ;-)

Внимательности и удачи вам! :)

Comment: В IF я вставил копию команды дроп... Пожалели составители задания знаки препинания.

А вот про MOVE поподробнее. Маленький я ещё, моей фантазии не хватает чтобы понять как это реализовать...

Ну, я конечно помню, что "программист должен учитывать все возможные, невозможные и ряд невероятных ситуаций", но в данном примере я задачу принимал за безусловно безошибочную.

Comment: А что вам подробнее? Описать, как работают ассоциативные массивы?))

Если есть

    $a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2342, 'c' => 'banan');

то после 

    $a['b'] = 123;
    $a['d'] = 321;

получите

    $a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 123, 'c' => 'banan', 'd' => 321);

Здесь, как видите, добавился только один элемент. С индексом `'d'` который. А `'b'` - заменился.

Теперь смотрите ваш код и ваше задание...

Comment: Ясно. Я просто сверхстранно понял задачу. Спасибо.